# How do I connect to the testnet blockchain without downloading it?

Tags: monerod, testnet, python, vps

I am building a python app that depends on both monerod, and the JSON-RPC server for access to the (testnet) blockchain. In my testing environment, I had access to more than enough space to hold the testnet blockchain, however now that I am deploying to a VPS, I no longer have that luxury. I am willing to give in to potential security risks.

My question is, what arguments do I have to run monerod with to connect with a public testnet node (like testnet.community.xmr.to) instead of automatically downloading the 2gb+ blockchain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand. `monerod` doesn't operate on a remote blockchain (other than syncing of course). You *can* however use the *wallet* (or another app, such as a python script) with a remote (or local) node via its JSON-RPC interface. This is almost certainly all you need (i.e. it's highly unlikely your python script *depends* on a local `monerod`).

A python example using a remote node:

```
import requests
import json

payload = {
        'jsonrpc':'2.0',
        'id':'0',
        'method':'get_block',
        'params': {
            'height': 101
            }
        }
rpc_url = 'http://testnet.community.xmr.to:28081/json_rpc'
req = requests.post(rpc_url, json=payload)
result = req.json().get('result')
print(result)
```

An example using the same remote node with either the `monero-wallet-rpc` or `monero-wallet-cli`, simply launch the wallet with:

```
--daemon-address testnet.community.xmr.to:28081
```

All this said, it is possible to start `monerod` with the `--no-sync` flag which will allow you to run the daemon and not sync the blockchain, but note, calling any RPC method which depends on blockchain data will fail in this mode.

Comment: my problem is that since i am using the monero-python sdk, i have to use the RPC server (not the problem since i can just run this on the VPS tbh) which connects to the ./monerod daemon. the monero daemon always by default begins by syncing a native copy of the blockchain, which must be downloaded on device. im asking if there is a way to make the monerod run on data from a public node (and more specifically, what the flags for the Bash command are). if i can connect directly to the node in the daemon Bash command, how would i do this? Thanks for the help!

Comment: https://imgur.com/9P6yx57

Comment: "im asking if there is a way to make the monerod run on data from a public node" <- No, as answered. Your *screenshot* in your comment shows you trying to use the *monero-wallet-rpc*, which absolutely can use a remote node (again as answered). To run the wallet RPC against a remote node you simply use `--daemon-address host:port` argument.

Comment: thank you so much! i think i just made a bunch of small mistakes that ended up creating a lot of problems, but now its working. have a great day!